# How to find special pattern via regex

Tags: java, regex

I have following regex which doesn’t match two different strings.

Actual regex which finds `AB-434`. Which doesn’t match `TEMS-54534`.

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+-[1-9][0-9]*)([^.]|\.[^0-9]|\.$|$)
```

**here is the sample inputs**

```
TEMS-54534

TEMS-5453

TEMS-1233

TEMS-12

CB-213
CB-2135
CB-12

ABC-2223
ABC-223
ABC-12
```

Comment: should it match any number/letter before and after the `-`?

Comment: Do you want to match 2-4 letters then 3-5 numbers, or exactly those combinations? Please give a list of input that should match and another list of input that should not match.

Comment: [It works?](https://regex101.com/r/tE0mM7/1)

Comment: Sorry , I have updated question with sample inputs

Comment: Based on your sample inputs you just need: `TEMS\-[0-9]{2,5}`

Comment: Well, what does `([^.]|\.[^0-9]|\.$|$)` stand for in the current pattern? What did you intend to match with that? Decimal/float values? Try [`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+-[1-9][0-9]*(?:[.][0-9]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/vY1bT5/1). **Please add the actual requirements to the question body**.

Comment: sorry for missing input examples, I need to cover others as we starting ABC-XX and CB-XX

Comment: Does the [`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+-[1-9][0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/vY1bT5/2) work? You know, without exact requirements, you can throw in more and more sample strings, and we can answer with more and more patterns that will all look similar, but not necessarily helpful.

Comment: @Wiktor  Thanks it workds

Comment: You seem to be looking for a pattern that starts with 1 ASCII letter followed with 1 or more alphanumeric or underscore characters followed with a `-` followed with one or more digits not starting with `0`. Please update the question with this description. I also understand it like you do not need to match `A-123`, right?

Comment: I posted an answer, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a pattern that starts with 1 ASCII letter followed with 1 or more alphanumeric or underscore characters followed with a `-` followed with one or more digits not starting with `0`.

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+-[1-9][0-9]*$
```

or

```
^[a-zA-Z]\w+-(?!0)\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY1bT5/2) (and [another one](https://regex101.com/r/vY1bT5/3)).

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+` / `[a-zA-Z]\w+` - an ASCII letter followed with 1+ alphanumerics/underscore chars
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[1-9][0-9]*` / `(?!0)\d+` - a digit from `1-9` range followed with 0+ nay digits (you can restrict it with `{min,max}` limiting quantifier if need be)
- `$` - end of string

More details:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be written as `\w` (if no [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) is used)
- In Java, do not forget to use double backslashes to escape metacharacters and shorthand character classes
- If the pattern is used with `String#matches()`, the `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the pattern are redundant.

And a [Java demo](http://ideone.com/Qmwp7c):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("TEMS-54534","TEMS-5453","TEMS-1233","TEMS-12","CB-213",
    "CB-2135","CB-12","ABC-2223","ABC-223","ABC-12");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str.matches("[a-zA-Z]\\w+-(?!0)\\d+"));
```

Comment: Or use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Yes, in Java it makes sense.